# What does putting a case class before function definition in scala mean?

Tags: scala, case-class

what is this syntax in scala

```
  final case class Transform[A, B](transform: A => Seq[B]) extends AnyVal


  override def newInstance() = Transform { myParameter: myParameter =>
    someOtherFunctionA(someOtherFunctionB.transform(myParameter)).toSeq
  }
```

What does putting a case class type before the function definition (before parameter) means?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I guess by "function" user16367669 means the method `override def newInstance...`

Comment: @DmytroMitin oh, why did I read `case keyword` instead of `case class`? Sorry for that, I deleted the comment.

Comment: `Transform { ... }` is the same as `Transform({ ... })`  which is the same as `Transform.apply({ ... })` which means we are just calling the `apply` method in the `Transform` companion object which just constructs a new instance of the class with the passed function.

Comment: There's no function definition in your code. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, you can have also have function values which are instances of `Function1[A, B]` or `A => B` (another way to write `Function1[A, B]`). This is no different from having an instance of `Integer` or `String`.

```
scala> val s: String = "abc"
// val s: String = abc

scala> val f: String => String = s => s + " added part"
// val f: String => String = $Lambda$1050/0x0000000800684040@632383b9
```

In Scala, case classes are defined as following

```scala
case class MyCaseClass(
  // these are constructor value members of the class
  s: String,
  // similar to above string member, your case class can also have a function member
  f: String => String
)
```

So, when you are writing

```scala
final case class Transform[A, B](transform: A => Seq[B]) extends AnyVal
```

You are just defining a `case class` which has a member of type `Function1[A, Seq[B]]` or `A => Seq[B]`.

Now, when you are creating an instance of this class, you will have to provide that `A => Seq[B]` value as constructor argument.

You can do it by explicitly definining the function value and then passing to constructor,

```scala
scala> val transformFunction: String => Seq[Char] = s => s.toCharArray.toIndexedSeq
// val transformFunction: String => Seq[Char] = $Lambda$1295/0x0000000800758840@20711b02

scala> val transformInstance: Transform[String, Char] = Transform(transformFunction)
// val transformInstance: Transform[String,Char] = Transform($Lambda$1295/0x0000000800758840@20711b02)
```

Or, you can directly provide the value

````scala
scala> val transformInstance: Transform[String, Char] = Transform { s: String => s.toCharArray.toIndexedSeq }
// val transformInstance: Transform[String,Char] = Transform($Lambda$1411/0x00000008007b4040@6dc010a2)```
````